# Trying to update and upgrade Ubuntu 22.04 fatal error GDK_IS_WAYLAND_WINDOW: not found

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I installed the onedriver package and it worked OK but now I want to uninstall it. During the installation it was said that I needed a file in /etc/environment which contained the statement GDK_IS_WAYLAND_WINDOW "wayland"

when trying to uninstall onedriver an error "GDK_IS_WAYLAND_WINDOW not found" is reported and the change fails .  But much worse, I can no longer perform apt upgrade which reports this error  after "Setting up install-info (6.8-4build1) ..."

Answer (score 0):

OK the problem was that the documentation I used was in error. It said to create a file /etc/environment and add a line
GDK_IS_WAYLAND_WINDOW "wayland"

The correct line is
GDK_IS_WAYLAND_WINDOW=wayland

That is an = and no quotes